# Fluid Templating Error TYPO3 8.4.1

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I recently set up a new test environment using TYPO3 v 8.4.1

I used the popular FLUID templating tutorial found on [typo3buddy.com](http://typo3buddy.com/typo3-template-tutorial/fluid/)

I've used this tutorial before on v6 and v7 projects.

My templates breaks (Ooops an error occurred) when I add the following block of code to the my home.html template:

```
<f:layout name="main_layout" />
<f:section name="content">
</f:section>
```

So that it now looks like this:

```
<f:layout name="main_layout" />
<f:section name="content">
<f:format.raw>{content_main}</f:format.raw>
</f:section>
```

When I use the this tutorial on a v7 install of TYPO3 I do not receive any error and the tempalte includes my layout file just fine.

Has something changed in v8?

TypoScript justincase,

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    format = html
    file = fileadmin/templates/home.html
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/partials/
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/layouts/
    variables {
        content_main < styles.content.get
        content_main.select.where = colPos = 0
}
```

Comment: By using:

    config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0

I was able to see the exact error message.

It would seem that my layout file (main_layout.html) need to be in camel case.

Changing the file to Main_Layout.html worked straight away.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a better Output of the Error you should enable the Develop ApplicationContext in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.domain$
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` in your TS setup. This will display error messages instead of hiding them.
Also make sure to select the `Development` preset in the Install Tool.

Make sure to switch all settings back to production once you are done debugging.